# Show custom field if it exists, and show different elements if it doesn't

Tags: php, custom-field

Basicly what I'm trying to do (with very basic knowledge of PHP):

```
If Custom Field $randomname exists for that particular post, show the content of that custom field.
If Custom Field $randomname doesn't exist for that particular post, show something else - for example: <div class="name">content</div>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the loop, you can check the custom field with `get_post_meta`. Like this.

If custom field `randomname` exists then it will show it's value otherwise it will print `<div class="name">content</div>`

```
<?php

    if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'randomname', true ) ) {

        echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'randomname', true );

    } else {

        echo '<div class="name">content</div>';

    }

?>
```

OR you can use below which is shorter version of above using Ternary Operator

```
    echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'randomname', true ) ?  get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'randomname', true ) :  '<div class="name">content</div>';
```